# Too many re-renders error when updating Router value with useState in a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a `React` App, in `Controller.jsx` file, I want to change `Route` and show related components. like this:

```
function Controller(props) {
  const [path, setPath] = useState("/home/");
  let componentToShow;

    function setPathAndComponent(newPath, newComponent) {
     setPath(newPath);
     componentToShow = newComponent;
    }

  switch (props.args.navigationValue) {
    case 0:
      setPathAndComponent("/home/", <Text />);
      break;

    case 1:
      args = { onClick: showLoginComponent };
      setPathAndComponent("/dashboard/", <Dashboard args={args} />);
      break;

    case 2:
      setPathAndComponent("/admin/");
      break;

    case 3:
      setPathAndComponent("/settings/");
      break;

    default:
      setPathAndComponent("/home/");
      break;
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Redirect to={path} />
       <Switch>
        <Route path="/home/">{componentToShow}</Route>
        <Route path="/home/main/">{componentToShow}</Route>
        <Route path="/dashboard/">{componentToShow}</Route>
        <Route path="/login/">{componentToShow}</Route>

      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default Controller;
```

But I get this error:

```
react-dom.development.js:14815 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I don't know how to prevent this. I need to change the root path value from entire project and it should be trigger new changes when a new url change arrived.

Comment: Redirect to path?